# Maximization problem setup and analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

So, I needed help in setting up the following:

> A coffee company sells two types of breakfast blends.  They have on hand $132$ kg of dark roast and $84$ kg of hazelnut.  One breakfast blend will contain half dark roast and half hazelnut and will sell for $\$7$ per kg. The other breakfast blend will contain $3/4$ dark roast and $1/4$ hazelnut and will sell for $\$9.50$ per kg.

My approach:

I see this is an optimization problem and need to show that $132x_1 + 84x_2$ needs to be optimized but confused on the other constraints

I used the convex optimization polygon theory of checking on the endpoints and computing the maximal value, can someone check and elaborate further on the reply below?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, no, I do not agree with your approach. Let $x_1$ denote the number of "blend 1" breakfasts and $x_2$ the number of "blend 2" breakfasts that the company will sell. Then you want to maximize the profit of the company, which is $$\max 7x_1+9.5x_2$$ subject to (the capacity constraints) $$\frac12x_1+\frac34x_2\le132\\\frac12x_1+\frac14x_2\le84$$ where $0\le x_1,x_2$.

Comment: Why did you make the restriction $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{N}$? Here $x_1$ and $x_2$ should be the weight of each blend produced, (in kilograms) which can be any nonnegative real number.

Comment: @smcc Thanks, I intented to delete this restriction by myself because I realised what you say but I forgot. Thanks, I am removing it.